# Rails and Devise - Send bad login feedback to client via Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, devise

I'm almost done modifying Devise to work with my custom login form, using AJAX. The only thing I have left to implement is getting messages about types of login failures (blank fields, incorrect credentials, etc.) to the custom form via AJAX when a user tries to log in incorrectly.

I have tried simply modifying the create method in sessions_controller.rb for Devise, like so:

```
def create
  super
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

And putting this code in create.js.erb for sessions views:

```
$("#complete_error").text("<%= "#{flash[:alert]}" %>");
$("#incorrect-log").removeClass("hidden");
```

This is not working at all. Even writing `puts flash[:alert]` in the controller to test if any alert is generated doesn't yield any results. I've tried following other guides on AJAX logins, but they were a bit confusing and also tended not to address exactly what I was looking for.

What do I need to do to get any login alerts, should they exit, to be sent back to the client on an unsuccessful login attempt?

**EDIT:**

401 Unauthorized error in log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2016-08-18 22:38:42 -0400
Processing by SessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"login"=>"aasdfasdf", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (lower(username) = 
  'aasdfasdf' OR lower(email) = 'aasdfasdf') ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Sessions Controller: (*Do I need to completely override the create method, not just super?*)

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:control_panel]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    super
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    super
  end

  def control_panel
    # Control panel page
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
console.log("<%= flash[alert] %>") #please review this in your inspect console browser (firebug)

$("#complete_error").text("<%= escape_javascript(flash[:alert]) %>");
```

**EDIT**

`https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.2.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L16`

when you call for super this is what happen:

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

warden

```
self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
```

but when this is executed and is false (the password or email wrongs) 
then your action create is terminated with `render nothing: true, status: 401`

will produce this `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)`

You have two choice override action create or study about warden custom authenticate [Warden strategy](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies)

**Example**

```
def create
  self.resource = User.find_by_email(sign_in_params[:email])
  if self.resource and self.resource.valid_password?(sign_in_params[:password])
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with self.resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  elsif self.resource.nil?
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    self.resource.errors.add(:email, I18n.t(:invalid_email, scope: [:devise, :failure], default: 'Invalid Email'))
    render :new
  elsif not self.resource.valid_password?(sign_in_params[:password])
    self.resource.errors.add(:password, I18n.t(:invalid_password, scope: [:devise, :failure], default: 'Invalid Password'))
    render :new
  end              
end
```

Comment: Nothing is printed in the console. On an incorrect login, the only thing in the console is the error `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in 401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: Is it what you spect ? You override the sessionController ?

Comment: I've overrided the session controller but I don't seem to be able to access the alerts, and it doesn't seem to be rendering the JS effectively

Comment: please show your session_controller.rb and part of development.log with this part `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in 401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: Added these things

Comment: devise version = 4.2.0

Comment: You did understand?

Comment: I'm just wondering if your example of a modified create action is as secure as using warden

Comment: Yes because I'am using the methods that devise give me to authenticate.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow and let you know what the results are.